# SQLite3 でデータベースファイルがロックされているかを確認する方法は？

Tags: python, sqlite

調べてみたのですが、単純にロック状態かどうかを判断する方法にたどり着けませんでした。
ご存知の方にご教示賜りたいと思います。

##### 目的：

データベースファイルがロック状態であれば、実行を停止して警告を出す。
データベースファイルアクセス開始時にすでにロック状態であるかを確認したい。
（具体的にはconnectコマンド前後の時点。）

##### 状況：

データベースファイルをユーザーが直接開いて、DB Browserなどで編集している場合、永続的に書き換えができないので、アプリケーション動作を停止して、警告を出す必要があります。

##### 問題点：

下記のサンプルコードのように、書き換えのコマンドinsertやupdateのクエリ実行時に、OperationalError 例外で警告を出すのでは遅すぎます。

##### ソースコードサンプル

```
import sqlite3

path = "./test.db"

'''
CREATE TABLE "TestTbl" (
    "pkey"  INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "name"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("pkey" AUTOINCREMENT)
)
'''

db = sqlite3.connect(path)

cursor = db.cursor()

sql_cmd = "select * from TestTbl"

cursor.execute(sql_cmd)
res = cursor.fetchall()

print(res)

sql_cmd = 'insert into TestTbl (name) VALUES ("test") '

try:
    cursor.execute(sql_cmd)
except sqlite3.OperationalError as e:
    raise e

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: こんな記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[Check if SQLite Databases Are Locked](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Check+if+SQLite+Databases+Are+Locked), [Sqlite python sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27160987/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。求める機能はなさそうですね。

Comment: ちょっと趣旨が違いますが、こんな記事から参考にできる何かが得られるかもしれませんね。[SQLite3で同時書き込みしたい](http://fanblogs.jp/scripts/archive/90/0)

Answer (score 1):

(環境が示されていないので 確認できる環境での回答)
※ ファイルロックの方法は OSにより違いがあるので, **環境が違うと**以下の操作は**動かないかも**しれません

POSIX準拠の OS, 少なくともファイルロックについて POSIXに準拠してるようなら, 次のように確認可能
(Linux各種ディストリ, ほか macOS でも可能なはず。他に FreeBSD NetBSD なども可能かもしれない)

参考: (docs.python.org) [利用可能性について](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/intro.html#availability)

#### 簡単な確認方法

sqlitebrowser にて, 内容変更 ⇛ 「適用」ボタン (コミット|ロールバック 行う手前で)
この状態で, `lslocks` コマンドで確認できます

```bash
$ lslocks | grep sqlite
sqlitebrowser    8824 POSIX  1.5G READ  0 1073741826 1073742335 sandbox/tempfile.sqlite
sqlitebrowser    8824 POSIX  1.5G WRITE 0 1073741825 1073741825 sandbox/tempfile.sqlite
```

- ロックのアクセス権限は, READでひとつ, WRITEでひとつ
- (ファイル内のロック位置が示されてるが, 未確認)

当該データベースがコマンド出力内に存在すれば, ファイルロックが行われていると見なしてよいでしょう

SQLite3の [File Locking](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) では次の 5 つのロック状態のいずれかになるという記載があり, いずれかの結果が現れているのでしょう

- UNLOCKED
- SHARED
- RESERVED
- PENDING
- EXCLUSIVE

#### Pythonコードでの判断

バッチ処理などの直前に, 自動で確認するのに向いているかもしれない処理
共有ロックを掛けてみて, 共有ロックできるようなら `WRITE`のロックは掛かっていないと判断できるでしょう

ただし, [`isolation_level`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level) のすべてを試したわけではないので, 保証はできません
また `os` パッケージにも同様の `os.lockf()`が存在するので, 何かあればそちらを使うのもよいかも

```py
import fcntl
import time

database = 'sandbox/tempfile.sqlite'
with open(database) as fp:
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(fp.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_SH | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        print('取得')

    except IOError as exc:
        # 失敗時はこのような例外 [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
        print('失敗', exc)

    finally:
        fcntl.lockf(fp.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        print('解除')
```